# How to fix the alignment of uPVC double glazing handle

Tags: windows

I wanted to replace the handle on one of my windows as it's getting stiff, unfortunately, the new handle won't close fully, on further inspection I realised the bolt for the lock inside the window is not level, when the window is closed. If I open the window and close the lock it doesn't have the same problem.

Is there a way to adjust the handle so that it matches the lock's misalignment?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Lubricating the metal sliding parts on the edge of the windows with light machine oil can cure the stiffness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not generally adjustable, but they do get stiff over time, they just get grimed up, which is usually why the handle breaks.

On the bottom edge of the open window there will be an access plate & also 4 lock bolts. There will also be two that slide out from the sides inline with these.
You can see the corresponding lock channels in the frame. These are not adjustable either.

WD40 in all 6 bolt slides/holes, in the handle mechanism & give it a good to & fro a dozen times with the window open.
If it's still not loosened sufficiently, then take the bottom plate off & inspect. I've never had one bad enough to need that, so I'm not exactly sure what you'll find. We're not on the ground floor, so it makes that a bit harder a task.

Check the bolts fit the channels smoothly too. With the locks freshly oiled, trap a couple of sheets of kitchen roll in the window as you close then lock it. See what's fitting & what's not. You might be able to loosen & tap a bit on the channel guides to gain a mm or so. You won't get much, as these are machine-fit. If the frame shifts badly over time you might eventually need to file bits out to keep the action clean.

After comments - I can't get a clean photo of any of this from the inside, so I've marked up a crop of the OP's photo as to where these are located. Each bolt on the window of course has a corresponding channel guide on the frame. The ones on the bottom edge will likely be little vertical rollers, the edges just flat plates, tapered to guide to the frame holes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, is it possible to ou can provide photos to help me understand?

Comment: You can't see them properly from the inside - so I've marked up a crop of your photo to show where they are.

Comment: I removed all the plates and did some trial and error, it's the two plates on the sides that cause the problem. I have left them off, for now leaving only the central one, I live on the 3rd floor there is no security risk.